# InfoPath 2013 form shakes, visual glitch

Tags: infopath

I've got an infopath form with 4 page views that connects to a SharePoint List. I've modified the form quite extensively and everything has been good so far, but recently when I select information from any control other than text fill the form twitches/shakes. This only happens in one view, I've tried removing and re-adding a few of the controls but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. is this a known issue in infopath? Or is there anything I could try to get the form to stop glitching?
Thanks

Edit: I just caught a pop-up and it seems like the form is trying to communicate with the server when a control box is accessed, but it's only on this one page still. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed a data connection and it stopped, looks like my server is not up for too many DCs.

Comment: +1 for posting the answer here instead of just abandoning the question. Come back in a few days and mark it correct!